# Error when deserialize JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

I try de-serialize using method with  JavaScriptSerializer but it doesnt work. Not sure what is diffrent between my code and this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp).

```
public void Main()
            {
              var dataResponse =@"{\"access_token\": \"NAonCg8KBHBpYXMSABoAJRAluFUSFAD2I2fXOrgvxInfWWG0UUsoqsby\", \"expires_in\": 28800}"

              JSON elements = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<JSON>(dataResponse);

              foreach (var item in elements.data) 
              {
                 MessageBox.Show(item.access_token.ToString());
              }

            } 
        public class JSON
            {
                public List<JSONElements> data { get; set; }
            } 
        public class JSONElements
            {
                public string access_token { get; set; }
                public int expired_in { get; set; }
            }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: try using this. `var dataResponse =@"{data: [{'access_token': 'NAonCg8KBHBpYXMSABoAJRAluFUSFAD2I2fXOrgvxInfWWG0UUsoqsby', 'expired_in': 28800}]}"` also would be better if you use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>()`

Answer (score 2):

First:

Your `json` string doesn't match properties in `JSONElements` class.The `int` member name is different.

Second:

Use `JSON.Net` while working with `json`.And you're deserializing to a **Wrong** type. Your `json` string doesn't contain any property `data`.It is an `JSONElements` object instead.

Third:

If you use the `@` symbol with a string then you cannot escape characters

So try like:

```
    var dataResponse =@"{'access_token':'NAonCg8KBHBpYXMSABoAJRAluFUSFAD2I2fXOrgvxInfWWG0UUsoqsby','expires_in':28800}";    
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONElements>(dataResponse);
```

And it works.

[image]

Comment: thank you for help and points i will correct it. But I cannot use JSON.NET.

Comment: You can use anything for this task, while `JSON.Net` is most popular and preferred way. Also, if you find the answer helpful, mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check string encoding. Maybe something like this will work

```
var dataResponse =@"{""access_token"": ""NAonCg8KBHBpYXMSABoAJRAluFUSFAD2I2fXOrgvxInfWWG0UUsoqsby"", ""expires_in"": ""28800""}";
```